# When do you require to use decltype in C++

Tags: c++

I am learning C++ and have found the following code in C++ primer:

```
int main() {

string s("some string");
for(decltype(s.size()) index = 0; index != s.size() && !isspace(s[index]); ++index)
    s[index] = toupper(s[index]);

cout << s;
```

}

I understand the code capitalized the first word in the string and the output is

```
SOME string
```

What I am curious is that why do you need to use `decltype(s.size())` to declare the type for index. If I change it to `int index =0`, the code still compile and run with no problem. It seems easier for me to use `int`. I think I am missing some import concept here, any feedback will be really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I think the point is that the return value of string::size() is unlikely to be an int, and using decltype gives you the correct type..

Comment: There is such a typedef known as `std::string::size_type`

Comment: Looks like a contrived example because in practice one would simply use `std::size_t` as the index type or get rid of the index variable by using range-for loop `for(auto& c: s){ if(isspace(c)) break; c = toupper(c); }`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not *required* to use `decltype(s.size())` to declare the type, but declaring it as `int` isn't necessarily a good idea. Or at least it's not a good habit to get into.

`decltype(s.size())` literally means "this type should be the same as whatever `std::string` uses to store the length of the string". In most C++ implementations, this is `size_t`, which will either be an unsigned 64-bit integer (in most cases) or an unsigned 32-bit integer. In either situation, `int` (which is signed and is probably not going to be 64-bits) is not going to represent the entire possible range of sizes for `std::string` objects, which could, in exotic situations, be greater than 2.1 billion characters. In those situations, if you defined the type as `int`, you'd run the risk of undefined behavior.

Note that in my code, I often just write `for(size_t index = 0; index < string.size(); index++)`, because that's simpler. But if you want to guarantee that the code will behave on all platforms, `for(decltype(string.size()) index = 0; index < string.size(); index++)` is the safest version of the code.

Comment: This isn't a question of guessing. `std::string::size_type` is specified clearly and unambiguously.

Answer (score 3):

The reson they used `decltype(s.size())` instead of `int` is because using `int` could cause a overflow which is undefined behavior.  `std::string::size()` returns a unsigned integer type that can store the largest size string you can make.  If `int` cannot hold that value and the string is that size then trying to run a `int` to that value will never work

Before C++11 you would have had to use `std::string::size_type` and if you changed the type then you would have to change the `std::string` part.  Now that we have C++11 and above we no longer need to do that.  The compiler knows what the type of things are so if we use `decltype(s.size())` we get the right type and if we ever change what `s` is there is nothing in the for loop that needs to be changed.  This is really nice from a maintainability stand point.

Answer (score 2):

Well, one place where decltype would be more useful would be:

```
template<class T1, class T2>
auto mul(T1 a, T2 b) -> decltype(a*b){
  return a*b;
}
```

This template will allow you to multiply two things together, possibly of different types, and will return something of the correct type of the result of multiplying the two together.   A hypothetical example might be multiplying two matricies together that results in some intermediate type class that defers the actual calculation until much later.

Comment: Thanks so much for your comment. As you know, I am learning C++ so I do not fully understand this line 'auto mul(T1 a, T2 b) -> decltype(a*b)' can you point me to a reference for better understanding?

Comment: Look up something called "trailing return types".  This is solving the problem that you can't talk about `a` or `b` where the return type normally goes because those identifiers haven't been declared yet.  So you can declare the return type as `auto` which essentially says "go look for the return type after the parameter list".  At which point `a` and `b` have been declared, and now `decltype` can use those identifiers to figure out the resultant type.  This is a C++11 thing.

Answer (score 1):

> When do you require to use decltype in C++

I can think of the following.

When you want the compiler to deduce a type from:

1. Another object's type.
2. A function's return type.

You could have also used:

```
auto size = s.size();
for(decltype(size) index = 0; index != size && !isspace(s[index]); ++index)
    s[index] = toupper(s[index]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that 
the type of `s.size()` member function of string class is `string::size_type` which is unsigned and can 
hold any length of string.
In this code `index` is a variable that increase as the loop runs and it will increase 
until its value becomes equal to `s.size()-1`.
The length of string can be of any size.So we can't use `int` for longer strings because it
can hold value of only specific range.So if string is longer in size `index` can hold the value 
of any size without showing any error.